# JavaScript - Shift Focus to Hovered Element

Tags: javascript, hover, focus

I have a set of buttons that trigger different functions on the page. The user can hover on the desired button and click on it, as normal, or can navigate through the buttons with the up and down arrow keys and press the enter key to trigger the corresponding function.

Using the arrow keys, the button that is currently focused has a different color from the others (green). Buttons that are hovered are also green.

As things are right now, it is possible for more than one button to be green: The hovered one and the focused one. I don't want this to happen.

The ideal solution would be to change the focus to whichever button is hovered. Is this possible? If so, how can I achieve this? Preferebly without resorting to jQuery.

This is what I am working with:

```js
        var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("move");
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
            inputs[i].addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
                if (event.keyCode == 38) {
                    if (this.previousElementSibling) {
                        this.previousElementSibling.focus();
                    }
                } else if (event.keyCode == 40) {
                    if (this.nextElementSibling) {
                        this.nextElementSibling.focus();
                    }
                }
            }, false);
```

```css
        .move {
            display: block;
            width: 200px;
            padding: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: aquamarine;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }

        .move:hover, .move:focus {
            background-color: greenyellow;
        }
```

```html
    <input class="move" type="button" value="1" autofocus />
    <input class="move" type="button" value="2" />
    <input class="move" type="button" value="3" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `mouseover` event with `focus` function for that. Should work fine...

```js
        var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("move");
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            inputs[i].addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
                if (event.keyCode == 38) {
                    if (this.previousElementSibling) {
                        this.previousElementSibling.focus();
                    }
                } else if (event.keyCode == 40) {
                    if (this.nextElementSibling) {
                        this.nextElementSibling.focus();
                    }
                }
            }, false);
            inputs[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {
                this.focus();
            }, false);
        }
```

```css
        .move {
            display: block;
            width: 200px;
            padding: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: aquamarine;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }

        .move:hover, .move:focus {
            background-color: greenyellow;
        }
```

```html
    <input class="move" type="button" value="1" autofocus />
    <input class="move" type="button" value="2" />
    <input class="move" type="button" value="3" />
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! This works just nice. It was still possible to have two different buttons styled as if they were both focused. I fixed that by deleting `.move:hover´ from the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a big fan of using mouseover to shift focus. If you don't want the hover state to display if a field has focus you can add a wrapping div and use focus-within.

As focus-within is not supported in ie and edge you can add mimic this using a .enable-hover class you toggle on focus/blur

```js
const wrapper = document.querySelector('.group');
[].slice
    .call(document.querySelectorAll('.move'))
    .map(input => {

      input.addEventListener('focus', e => {
          wrapper.classList.remove('enable-hover')
      });

      input.addEventListener('blur', e => {
          wrapper.classList.add('enable-hover')
      });
      
      input.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
          if (e.keyCode == 38 && input.previousElementSibling)
            input.previousElementSibling.focus();
          if (e.keyCode == 40 && input.nextElementSibling)
            input.nextElementSibling.focus();
      });     
  })
```

```css
.group:not(:focus-within) > .move:hover,
.group.enable-hover > .move:hover, 
.move:focus {
  background: greenyellow;
 }  

.move {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
    <input class="move" type="button" value="1" autofocus />
    <input class="move" type="button" value="2" />
    <input class="move" type="button" value="3" />
</div>
```

Comment: If I run that code snippet, it works fine... until I run it in full page mode. Than, it stops working as intended. Once a button is focused with the arrow keys, I can no longer focus with by hovering. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: This example does not set focus on hover. IMO it's bad practice to do so (mixing states is both confusing, annoying and bad for accessibility). The hover is disabled if a button has focus and enabled when none has.

Comment: If you click outside the buttons hover is enabled – but you can no longer use arrows (expected behaviour as this requires focus on element)

Comment: I understand your concerns. However, I don't believe accessibility will be a problem in this very specific case I am working on. And regarding your last comment, I worked around that by adding an event listener that shifts the focus to the first button, whenever an arrow key is pressed when no element is focused. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: You are welcome :-). PS. be careful with adding focus on arrow keys if you add more focusable elements (radio button groups uses arrows to 'tab').